# Projectile installed but "Autoloading failed to define function projectile-mode"

Tags: init-file, projectile

I can `M-x projectile-mode` (I get this and other projectile commands in the completion list) but it fails with

> Autoloading failed to define function projectile-mode

Projectile is an installed package, according to `package-list-packages`:

> projectile         20150724.1312 installed

(And I can use `C-h f` to search for the function and to open the `projectile.el` file.)

When I add `(require 'projectile)` to my `init.el`, startup fails with

> error: Required feature `projectile' was not provided

Emacs 24.5 on OSX installed via Homebrew, using the Emacs Live (git rev 170bddd, 2015-07-18) setup.
Here is [my Emacs config](https://github.com/jakubholynet/dotfiles/tree/80e6e1154d0318b353569250f242d9f15ad8b230/.live-packs/jholy-pack) (as an Emacs Live pack).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So re-installing projectile fixed it - but on the next start, the problem was back :-( No other package has this issue.

Comment: Do you have `(package-initialize)` in your init?

Comment: Yes, I do - you can [see my init.el here](https://github.com/jakubholynet/dotfiles/blob/80e6e1154d0318b353569250f242d9f15ad8b230/.live-packs/jholy-pack/init.el)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got the error "Autoloading failed to define function" because multiple packages are apparently active in your load-path. Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-load-path-shadows` to get a clue which packages are conflicting.

Comment: From the list... how do we know whats wrong? I have 151 lisp load-path shadowings