# Ghost code in Emacs configuration, how to find it?

Tags: autoload

I use the package `vimish-fold`.

The package contains, for example, two functions, called as:

```
Function 1
Function 2
```

There is a new commit to the package `vimish-fold` on Github, which will add the new function 3. But the changes are not reflected yet in MELPA. 
I wanted to try it out, so I upgrade it manually.

I made the mistake of changing the contents of the package manually.

I copied the new code from Github, pasted the new code over the old code in the `.el`-file in the same package. And in the same package, I bytecompiled manually the `.el`-file in the same directory. So the `.elc`-file is also updated.

After restarting Emacs, I don't see the `function 3` appearing when calling the commands lists with <kbd>M-x</kbd>.

After that, I deleted the package `vimish-fold` in `package.el` and reinstalled it. I waited until the update for `vimish-fold` appeared in MELPA, and update it with `package.el`.

In the same Emacs session, the new features of `vimish-fold` works fine, like `function 3`. But when I restarted Emacs, I see the new commands when I do <kbd>M-x</kbd>:

```
Function 1
Function 2
Function 3
```

I call the `function 3`, I get the message `"Autoloading failed to define function function 3"` But the `function 1` and `function 2` works fine, except the new `function 3`. So I guess somewhere the old package is still active. Then I remove the package `vimish-fold` in `package.el`, and reinstall it. In the same Emacs session the `function 3` works again. But when I restarted Emacs, `Function 3` is visible in the list of all commands, but I get the same error when I call the `function 3`.

So it seems the right package is enabled, but I get the autoloading fail error again. Note this is after deleting and reinstall the same package with the MELPA package manager/paradox.

It seems [the others also struggled with the same issue. Without any succes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/projectile-installed-but-autoloading-failed-to-define-function-projectile-mode). When I do a grep, I can't find any other same package as `vimish-fold`. Notice that I use Windows, and I have my `.emacs.d` in my PATH.

Any suggestion in order to solve it?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` might give you a clue (IOW it's not a ghost, just a shadow).

Comment: @Stefan thanks for your reply. The `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` helped me to find the culprit. This issue is solved by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue of "Autoloading failed to define function" is solved now. Try `M-x list-load-path-shadows` to get a clue which packages are conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

To install a package from a package file (in your case, that is `vimish-fold.el`) with `package.el`, you can use `package-install-from-buffer` or `package-install-file`. It will byte-compile elisp code AND create an autoload file correspondingly. Thus,

> I bytecompiled manually the .el-file in the same directory. So the .elc-file is also updated.

is not enough, then it will happen:

> After restarting Emacs, I don't see the function 3 appearing when calling the commands lists with M-x.

---

While using `pakckage.el`, for safety, you usually need to keep only one specific version and can activate only one specific version, so remove duplicate package of different versions if you have. and don't install package again manually, that is, put `vimish-fold.el` into somewhere of your `load-path` by yourself.

---

I don't understand your other questions.

Comment: Your answers focus on my previous mistake of changing the contents of the package. After that, I deleted the package `vimish-fold` in `package.el` and reinstalled it. In same emacs session, the new features of `vimish-fold` works fine. But when I restarted Emacs, I see the new commands when I do <kbd>M-x</kbd>, but when I'm calling it, I get the message: `"Autoloading failed to define function vimish-fold-toggle"`. How can I solve it?

Comment: @ReneFroger That error message means "vimish-fold-toggle is an autoload command from `vimish-fold.el`, but actually, the actived `vimish-fold.el` doesn't define that command"

Comment: @ReneFroger You have to make sure the version of `vimish-fold`, which has the autoload vimish-fold-toggle command, is activated in `package.el`, the way to check is to use `C-h P` of `find-function`.