# conflicting libraries Autoloading failed to define function: problem sending mail with gnus

Tags: gnus

When I'm in gnus and type m
I got the following error 
`gnus-group-mail: Autoloading failed to define function gnus-nnir-group-p`

I couldn't not find the function `gnus-nnir-group-p`

From this [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/projectile-installed-but-autoloading-failed-to-define-function-projectile-mode) , i tried `M-x list-load-path-shadows` and think I've found the culprit. I'm still trying to sort this out. Any idea?

```
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/gnus-bonus/spam-stat hides /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus/spam-stat
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/gnus-bonus/nnir hides /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus/nnir
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/gnus-bonus/nnnil hides /usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus/nnnil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I was too quick to rely on your help. 
I found the answer [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ConflictingLibraries). It was indeed a problem of conflicting libraries. I just put the "right" library up the `load-path` in my `.emacs` as recommended :

```
(setcar load-path "/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/gnus")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-20150716.643/")
```

I'll modify a little bit the title for the question to be more general. Thanks